# TestCafe - How can I determine the mouse cursor (pointer) shape when over certain HTML elements

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe, mouse-cursor

I am trying to write a TestCafe functional test around drag and drop.  I already have drag and drop working and I am trying to test the source/target functionality by trying to drag an element onto a part of the screen it is not allowed to drop.  The mouse cursor shape changes to the "No entry" symbol when the drop is not permitted during the mouse hover.  I cannot see anywhere in the TestCafe documentation where I can interrogate the mouse cursor icon shape.

I cannot see any documentation on this in TestCafe.
Does TestCafe support this?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 2):

[TestCafe selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/) specify an element on the testing page and return an object with a set of properties and methods to the server.
Read more about Selector's properties in [TestCafe docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html).

You can use the `getStyleProperty` method to verify the cursor style of an element, e. g.

```js
.expect(Selector('div').getStyleProperty('cursor')).eql('no-drop');
```

In any other cases, when you need to get specific information about a DOM element, you can use a combination of [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) and [Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/). This scenario may look as follows:

```js
const el = Selector('#editable-div');

    const getCursorStyle = ClientFunction(() => {
        return window.getComputedStyle(el()).cursor;
    }, {dependencies: {el}})

    await t
        .drag(Selector('#create'), -14, -255, {
            offsetX: 38,
            offsetY: 11
        })
        .expect(getCursorStyle()).eql("no-drop");
```

You can even use a more advanced approach - [implementing `addCustomDOMProperties`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#accessing-page-element-properties), especially if you need to check the added property several times.